# Bootstrap HTML Validator Warning: Element nav does not need a role attribute

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, navigation, role

I have insert a menu in my index:

```
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
```

But when I try to validate it (in local) the validator.w3 tell me:

> Warning: Element nav does not need a role attribute.

I can't find a solution, can someone help me?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_nav_element#Example%3aThe_.3Cnav.3E_element

Note: When support for HTML5 improves there may be no need to continue to add the ARIA role="navigation".

Comment: Ok, so I don't need it.. Thanks YvesLeBorg

Comment: Does this not help for older browser support? I received the same error when checking validation. I removed it and saw no difference in terms of how the site performed...but i still wondering about older browsers.

Answer (score 9):

Delete `role="navigation"`.

The `<nav>` element already has the semantics of being for navigation. You don't need to add them with the `role` attribute. Saying "This navigation element is for navigation" is redundant and silly.

```
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navbar navbar-default">
```